# How do I change solr.solr.home for Solr installed via HomeBrew?

Tags: macos, solr, homebrew

`solr.solr.home` is set to `/usr/local/Cellar/solr/4.10.2/example/solr`, but I'd like to change it. I tried several things including setting a `SOLR_HOME` environment variable and setting the `s` program var in `/usr/local/Cellar/solr/4.10.2/homebrew.mxcl.solr.plist`
, which sets `solr.solr.home` according to the comments in the `solr` script file.

> -s  Sets the solr.solr.home system property; Solr will create core directories under this directory. This allows you to run multiple Solr instances on the same host while reusing the same server directory set using the -d parameter. If set, the specified directory should contain a solr.xml file. The default value is example/solr. This parameter is ignored when running examples (-e), as the solr.solr.home depends" on which example is run."

I'm approaching this wrong, but I don;t know what else to try.

Edit: I'm starting solr with `solr start`.

Answer (score 1):

How are you starting Jetty (default Solr container)? There should be a command that runs *java -jar start.jar*. That's where you add *-Dsolr.solr.home=xyz* as a java parameter (before -jar).

Comment: I edited my question to answer your question. I found the script called `solr` in `/usr/local/Cellar/solr/4.10.2/bin`. I'll try directly editing the script.

Answer (score 0):

I came across an issue on the Homebrew Solr 5.2.0 installation where it wouldn't remember my core configurations (which were placed in nonstandard locations) whenever the server was restarted.  I fixed it by creating a `cores` directory in the brew solr directory and creating a symlink to my core:

```
mkdir $(brew --prefix solr)/server/solr/cores
ln -s ~/Documents/my-application/solr $(brew --prefix solr)/server/solr/cores/my-application
```

And inside `~/Documents/my-application/solr` I have:

```
ls -al solr/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   7 adam  staff  238 Jul  2 08:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 adam  staff  884 Jun 25 08:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 adam  staff  136 Jul  2 08:05 conf
-rw-r--r--   1 adam  staff  132 Jul  2 08:02 core.properties
drwxr-xr-x   4 adam  staff  136 Jun 23 08:17 data
drwxr-xr-x   4 adam  staff  136 Jul  2 07:27 index
drwxr-xr-x   2 adam  staff   68 Jul  2 07:27 tlog

solr/conf:
total 152
drwxr-xr-x  4 adam  staff    136 Jul  2 08:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 adam  staff    238 Jul  2 08:23 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff   2647 Jun 18 09:02 schema.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff  70771 Jun 23 08:12 solrconfig.xml
```